# With CSS media print, can I specify the height attribute of an element in inches?

Tags: css

I would like to make sure the height attribute of an element to be in inches instead of pixels for printing a page using CSS.  How can accomplish this?

Comment: Set up a print version of your CSS, and swap it in for your regular HTML css when the user goes to a print view.  Then just replace your `px` with `in`.

Answer (score 2):

Css Class:

```
.class
{
    height: __in;
}
```

Inline:

```
<element style="height: __in;"></element>
```

[CSS Values and Units Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537660%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

There's actually an "inch" unit for measurement. Just specify the value in `in`:

```
<div id="inches" style="height:1in;"></div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XjZVh/1/

```
...
<link href=".../print.css" media="print" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<body>
<div id="InchesForPrint"></div>
...
```

regular css: `#InchesForPrint { height:100px; }`

print.css: `#InchesForPrint { height:5in; }`